# How to set CMS page as homepage in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Can anyone please help me with is question here.

I want to set a **CMS page** as homepage in prestashop 1.6 and still able to keep the **old default Prestashop homepage** as my Shop button link in menu still?  please.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good requirement. In order to achieve this you need to edit some core files on your store.

- Open /controllers/front/IndexController.php

Add the following code to the initContent() function

`if (!Tools::isSubmit('home'))
        Tools::redirect('contact');`

Replace the 'contact' to the controller of any CMS page based upon your requirements.

- Open /themes/YOUR_THEME/header.tpl

Search for

`{if isset($force_ssl) && $force_ssl}{$base_dir_ssl}{else}{$base_dir}{/if}`

Replace with

`{if isset($force_ssl) && $force_ssl}{$base_dir_ssl}?home=1{else}{$base_dir}?home=1{/if}`

Comment: Thank you for your replay! but may I ask, for the added in code in IndexController.php
'contact', **should I use url link? or I should but cms page ID to replace 'contact'**?

and **I can not find the code that should be replaced in header.tpl**, can you please help? THANK YOU!